# How do I Generate rows depending upon the column value in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, rows, using, generate

suppose If I have single column with one row

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  4|
+---+
```

then how do i generate rows depending up on the value of a column

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
| 1 |
|---|
| 2 |
|---|
| 3 |
|---|
| 4 |
+---+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `udf` function for that *to generate range* and then use `explode` function to make them *to separate rows*

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
def generateUdf = udf((column: Int)=> (1 to column).toArray)

df.withColumn("id", explode(generateUdf(col("id")))).show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+---+
|id |
+---+
|1  |
|2  |
|3  |
|4  |
+---+
```